# HTML email for Outlook 2007: adding an image

Tags: html, image, email, outlook-2007

I'm designing an html email to be read using Outlook 2007.

I want to add an image, a logo, positioned first thing on the email.

How do I include an image? I feel like I need a path to do the usual:

```
<img src=”mypath/image.gif”>
```

But I don’t think I can include paths to anything.  What should I do?

Thanks a ton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference an attached image using the [`cid:` scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2392).

In general, you would let a tool handle this for you. Last time I had cause to do this, I write the program that sent the mail in [Perl](http://www.perl.org/) and used the [`Email::MIME::CreateHTML` module](https://metacpan.org/module/Email::MIME::CreateHTML).

Comment: HTML is a data format. You can't construct MIME with it. You can either do it by hand, or use software to do it for you.